# Deriving expressions from transfer function of state variable filter?

Tags: frequency, transfer-function, active-filter

I have been trying to design a state variable filter based on a block diagram provided. The transfer function which I have is of the form:

$$\frac{K_1K_2}{s^2 + K_1s + K_1K_2}$$

I need to obtain and derive expressions for the **natural frequency** and **quality factor** of the state variable filter in terms of \$K_1\$ and \$K_2\$. In order to do so I need to compare my T.F with a 2nd order normalized T.F for state variable filters. Below is the T.F I am comparing with from [this](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/state-variable-filter.html) website.

$$\frac{V_{\text{out}}}{V_{\text{in}}} = \frac{A_o\left(\frac{f}{f_o}\right)}{\left[1 + 2\zeta\frac{f}{f_o} + \left(\frac{f}{f_o}\right)^2\right]}$$

I am getting confused since the 2nd order normalized T.F does not have an \$s^2\$ term.

For the natural frequency I have got:

$$\omega_n\text{ or }\frac{f}{f_o} = \sqrt{K_1K_2}$$

and for the quality factor:

$$2\zeta\omega_n = K_1s$$
$$\zeta = \frac{K_1s}{2\sqrt{K_1K_2}}$$

My question is: Am I comparing to the right transfer function since it does not have s squared terms? If so have I proceeded correctly? If not, are there any tips on what I could do to derive the above expressions correctly?

Comment: Your TF equation is correct, the website is wrong, all the 's' variables are missing. Also \$2\zeta \omega_n=K_1\$; 's' is the Laplace variable and doesn't have a numerical value in this context - it's the coefficient of s that you need.

Comment: @Chu thanks for your comment, so I guess the explanation given below is indeed correct.

Comment: Yes - the "tutorial" of the referenced website is totally wrong!!

Comment: @LvW, thanks, that was the main reason I was confused!

Comment: I left a written comment/correction at the site, but it was not considered. My recommendation: Do not rely on such tutorials. Instead, consult a good textbook (several good books are available online).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transfer function of a second-order low pass filter is given by ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor#Physical_interpretation)):

$$H(s)=\frac{\omega_0^2}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_0 s+\omega_0^2}\tag{1}$$

where \$\omega_0\$ is the resonant frequency (in radians), and \$\zeta\$ is the damping ratio.

Comparing \$(1)\$ to your transfer function you get

$$\omega_0=\sqrt{K_1K_2}$$

and

$$\zeta=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{K_1}{K_2}}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mentioned that is the transfer function of a second-order low pass filter, however the transfer function in question here is that of a state variable filter. Does it still apply?

Comment: @Rrz0: Yes, a state variable filter is just a certain structure to implement a filter characteristic. Your transfer function is a second-order low pass filter.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you got the value for the damping factor? I am getting (1/2) K1/sqrt(K1K2)

Comment: @Rrz0: ... which is the same as the one I got, because \$K_1/\sqrt{K_1}=\sqrt{K_1}\$ :)

Comment: The frequency wo is not the "resonant" frequency but the so called "pole frequency". At this frequency the phase shift is -90deg. In contrast, "resonance" is defined for a frequency dependenet system at the point where the phase sift is zero.

Comment: @LvW: The pole frequency is the imaginary part of the pole location: \$s_{\infty}=\sigma+j\omega_p\$, and for the given example it is \$\omega_p=\omega_0\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\$. In most textbooks I know, the frequency \$\omega_0\$ in Eq. (1) is called 'resonant frequency'.

Comment: @Matt: I rather think, the pole frequency is the magnitude of the vector directed to the complex pole - that means: The pole frequency is the square root taken from the sum of the squared values of the real and the imag. part of the pole. For the given example and without any doubt the pole frequency wp is identical to wo. This is because the denumerator of H(s) is written in the so called "normal form" (s² +...+ wo²). A lowpass has no "resonant frequency" - just a corner frequency and a pole frequency (which are identical for a Butterworth approximation).

Comment: @LvW: I'm used to using different semantics here, but as long as we know what we're talking about that's OK I guess. For me the term "pole frequency" makes most sense when it refers to the actual frequency of the pole, which is its imaginary part. And any second-order system with complex conjugate poles has a resonance frequency, it doesn't need to be a band pass system. If the poles are on (or very close) to the imaginary axis resonance becomes very visible.

Comment: @Matt: Of course, you can use your own semantics. However, in this case, misunderstandings are unavoidable. I am very familiar with a lot of filter books - and I am sure: There are fixed and agreed definitions for the term "pole frequency" as well as "resonance". Of course, for very high Q-factors we can be close to resonance (zero deg phase shift). Nevertheless, a lowpass - in particular with low Q values like Q=0.707 - has no resonanat frequeny. By the way: Tabulated filter parameters (to be found in textbooks) are wp and Qp (with wp according to my definition above).

Comment: @LvW: It's not only my personal semantics. We've both probably read quite a few books, so let's not argue about who is right or wrong. It's about conventions, and there is more than one convention. Just one example: in "Foundations of Analog and Digital Electronic Circuits" by A. Agarwal (which is used by quite a few universities), \$\omega_0\$ as used in my answer is called "resonant frequency", for any second-order system (also for a low pass). What you call resonant frequency is called (in the book) "damped resonance frequency", i.e., the actual frequency of the damped sinusoid.

Comment: @Matt: Independent on terminology - one thing is clear without any doubt and can be shown using basic math: The term "wo" in the function H(s) is not the imag. part of the pole location - rather, it is the length of the vector from the origin to the complex pole. See for example Sedra/Smith, Fig. 12.15: "...observe that the radial distance of the natural modes from the origin is equal to wo, which is known as the pole frequency." Based on this definition the real part of the pole is identical to (-d*wo) and the imag. part gives the natural frequency wn=wo*SQRT(1-d²) . For d=0 we have wn=wo.

Comment: @LvW: I'm not sure why you're telling me that w0 is not the imag. part of the pole. I know that, and I've never claimed anything else. Nothing in your previous comment is new to me, and that formula for the natural frequency is the same that I've written down in one of my previous comments, where I've said that this is the imag. part of the pole (called "natural frequency" or, by some including myself, "pole frequency"). Not sure what you're trying to prove here.

Comment: @Matt: My only intention is and was (a) to clarify the term "pole frequency" - as it is used in ALL books I have consulted within the last 25 years (see my ref. to Sedra/Smith) and (b) to comment on the misleading term "resonant frequency" in conjunction with a lowpass response - in particular to a Butterworth approximation which has no magnitude peaking at all. There is no resonant point because resonance is defined for a phase shift of zero! The phase shift of a second-order lowpass at the pole frequency is exactly -90 deg.

Comment: I like to add that the imag. part of the pole frequency wp (magnitude of the pole location) is called "natural frequency wn", which can be measured using the step response (frequency of the damped sinusoidal response for small damping values ).

Comment: @LvW: "imaginary part of the pole frequency"? The pole frequency is real-valued, you must mean something else. I think you mean the imaginary part of the pole location, which is indeed also called the "natural frequency" or "damped resonant frequency".

Comment: Matt - yes you are right. I have used a bad (wrong) expression. Of course, it is the imag. part of the pole location. Sorry.